# using regex in jinja 2 for ansible playbooks

Tags: python, regex, jinja2, ansible

HI i am new to jinja2 and trying to use regular expression as shown below

```
{% if ansible_hostname == 'uat' %}
   {% set server = 'thinkingmonster.com' %}

{% else %}
   {% set server = 'define yourself' %}
{% endif %}

{% if {{ server }} match('*thinking*') %}
  {% set ssl_certificate = 'akash' %}

{% elif {{ server }} match( '*sleeping*')%}
   {% set ssl_certificate = 'akashthakur' %}
{% endif %}
```

based on the value of "server" i would like to evaluate as which certificates to use.
ie if domain contains "thinking" keyword then use these certificates and if it contains "sleeping" keyword  then use that certificate.

But didn't found any jinja2 filter supporting this.
Please help me.I found some python code and sure that can work but how to use python in jinja2 templates?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand correct: you want to have a filter that maps a value according to which regex it matches?

Comment: @bereal yes that what i all want.But not able  to do so

Comment: {% if {{ server }} match('*thinking*') %}
  {% set ssl_certificate = 'akash' %}   if value of serve contains thinking keyword then value of ssl_certificate should be 'akash'

Comment: why jinja2 has no filter to check sub-string.That would have solved my purpose

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have a map of server name to ssl cert?

Comment: Yes because there were 100+ server-names so using dict would be difficult .And server-names also keep on changing .Whats common in all names is two keywords so if i used dict all keys will be having only either value1 or value 2. Also use of dict would have made things lil bit static and would have to lot many dict functions to manipulate the same.

Comment: I see you found a solution for your problem, but I think it would be better to not solve this in the template. Which certificate is being used or to which environment a host belongs to, should be handled by host groups. In your inventory assign hosts to groups and then set the appropriate parameters in the corresponding group_vars file(s).

Comment: @udndan ,Yes that can also be done  but problem here is like that suppose  i have "thinkingmonster" app running on dev,qa,uat and production env and everywhere different certificates are being used for each env.There are 100 application like this.Also its not specific that an environment will always use  a particular type of certificates.So group_vars would have made things more static  where as in templates templates themselves decide as which certificate to use

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Jinja2 can quite easily do substr checks with a simple 'in' comparison, e.g.

```
{% set server = 'www.thinkingmonster.com' %}
{% if 'thinking' in server %}
   do something...
{% endif %}
```

So your substring regex filter isn't required.  However if you want more advanced regex matching, then there *are* in fact filters available in ansible - see the regex filters in http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters - funnily enough, your match syntax above is nearly exactly right.

+1 for [Bereal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413899/2947502) though, it gives a nice alternative in the form of a map.

Answer (score 16):

There is a "regex_replace" filter available in Ansible>1.6

[Other Useful Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters)
Scroll down and you'll see this:

> New in version 1.6.

To replace text in a string with regex, use the “regex_replace” filter:

```
# convert "ansible" to "able"
{{ 'ansible' | regex_replace('^a.*i(.*)$', 'a\\1') }}

# convert "foobar" to "bar"
{{ 'foobar' | regex_replace('^f.*o(.*)$', '\\1') }}

# convert "localhost:80" to "localhost, 80" using named groups
{{ 'localhost:80' | regex_replace('^(?P<host>.+):(?P<port>\\d+)$', '\\g<host>, \\g<port>') }}
```

That being said, regex is overkill for finding a solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to Steve E. hint, I've figured out a way to add regex in a template condition:

```
{% if server | regex_search('thinking') %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 7):

So after googling for a long time and with the help of some bloggers here is the final solution to my problem:-

**1.** Jinja2 does not have any filter for finding sub-string or regexp, so the only solution was to create a custom filter. I followed the steps  below to fix my problem.

**2.** Inside the root directory of my playbook, I created a directory ***"filter_plugins"*** and wrote a custom module in python and placed the file inside this directory. The name of the python file can be anything. My python code looks as follows:

```py
 __author__ = 'akthakur'
class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Custom filters are loaded by FilterModule objects '''

    def filters(self):
        ''' Filter Module objects return a dict mapping filter names to filter functions. '''
        return {
            'substr': self.substr,
        }

        ''' def substr(self, check,checkin):
        return value1+value2'''
    def substr(self,check,checkin):
         if check in checkin:
            return True
         else:
            return False
```

**3.** Once this file is created our brand new filter ***"substr"***  is ready to use and can be used inside templates as shown below:

```
{% if 5==5 %}
 {% set server = 'www.thinkingmonster.com' %}
{% endif %}
{% if 'thinking' | substr(server) %}
   {% set ssl_cert = 'abc.crt'%}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please note that this answer is pretty outdated, there are regex filters in Ansible now: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters

Answer (score 3):

There are some (currently) undocumented filters in Ansible 2.1 which may do what you need:
[Ansible plugins/filter.core.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.2.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py)

The **regex_search** filter will perform a regex on the string and return the resulting match. Something similar to this would work and be contained within an Ansible role:

```
{% set server = 'www.thinkingmonster.com' %}
{% if regexp_search(server, 'thinking') %}
   do something...
{% endif %}
```

There is also a **regex_findall** filter which performs a Python findall search instead of regex.

[Review the original pull request for further information](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/14696)

Comment: When trying to use this technique with Ansible 2.2 I get `AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'regex_search' is undefined`

Comment: My bad. I was using Ansible 2.1 and `regex_search` is available from 2.2

Comment: regex_search was released in the [2.1.0.0 build](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.0.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py)

Comment: I get "'regex_search' is undefined" on Ansible 2.2.1.0.

Comment: I get the undefined error with both `regex_search` and `regexp_search` -- using Ansible 2.3.1.0.

Comment: `regex_search` is a filter so it should be used as `{% if server|regexp_search('thinking') %}`

Answer (score 3):

This is rather ugly, but it works as of 1.6.

```
{% if server|regex_replace('.*thinking.*','matched') == 'matched' %}
  {% set ssl_certificate = 'akash' %}

{% elif server|regex_replace('.*sleeping.*','matched') == 'matched' %}
   {% set ssl_certificate = 'akashthakur' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no builtin filter for that in Jinja2 neither among Ansible's [extra filters](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html), but it's not a big deal to make your own:

```
certs = {'.*thinking.*': 'akash', '.*sleeping.*': 'akashthakur'}
def map_regex(value, mapping=certs):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        if re.match(k, value):
            return v
```

Then you'll need to add a [filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) to Ansible, so that it will use the function above in templates (like `{{server|ssl_cert}}` if you name the filter `ssl_cert`).

That said, a plain old function or a plain old dictionary that is passed to the templates and used there explicitly might fit this job better.