# How can I easily extract some HTML attribute value from html page using ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to obtain a specific meta attribute value from a html page which is loaded using ansible uri module.

How can I get this attribute inside an ansible variable?

Comment: Maybe a Regex Filter with Jinja2?  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters

Comment: Another solution (much cleaner) would be a custom filter_plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413616/using-regex-in-jinja-2-for-ansible-playbooks

Comment: @el_wichtel I am starting to like the filter approach as it could easily be implemented using BeautifulSoup4. Don't forget to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins

Some examples could be found here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py