# How use regular expression with if condition in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

How use regular expression with if condition in Jinja2. I want to do as below in a template:

```
{% if varaibletotest regexcomparison '^(.*).level2.level3.level4$' -%}   
    do something for if condition
{% else -%}
    do something for else condition
{% endif  -%}
```

Please help me in syntax

Comment: What back-end are you using?

Comment: We are using Ansible to deploy templates on servers. Please inform us, if you have any questions

Comment: Jinja2 don't have regex right out of the box unless you create a custom filter.. similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413616/using-regex-in-jinja-2-for-ansible-playbooks